# How Force replace macro apply on header also

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I want to find & replace a text in word document. I created a macro as bellow.

```
Sub Macro1()
  ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="#Text1", ReplaceWith:="acca", _
     Replace:=wdReplaceAll   
End Sub
```

It replaced all occurred but not in header/footer!!
How forced to work on entire document include header/body/footer?

Comment: There are a [few ideas in this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[word-vba]%20%2Breplace%20%2Bfooter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've always used this VBA code to Find/Replace, and it will do Headers/Footers along with the body of the document:

```
    Dim myStoryRange As Range


        For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        With myStoryRange.Find
            .Text = "Text to find to replace goes here"
            .Replacement.Text = "And the replacement text goes here"
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        Do While Not (myStoryRange.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set myStoryRange = myStoryRange.NextStoryRange
            With myStoryRange.Find
                .Text = "Text to find to replace goes here"
                .Replacement.Text = "And the replacement text goes here"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Loop
    Next myStoryRange
```

You can also copy and paste it a bunch of times in the same Sub to replace different strings at the same time.

Comment: +1 for the workaround. The only problem is when you had "paste it a bunch of times in the same sub" the macros become really slow...

Answer (score 1):

There should be a better way, but I cannot find it:

```
Sub ReplaceHeaderFooterandBody(findString As String, replaceString As String)
ActiveDocument.Windows(1).View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryHeader
With Selection.Find
        .Text = findString
        .Replacement.Text = replaceString
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Windows(1).View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryFooter
With Selection.Find
        .Text = findString
        .Replacement.Text = replaceString
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Windows(1).View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
With Selection.Find
        .Text = findString
        .Replacement.Text = replaceString
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

It appears that Word refuses to search an area unless it's your current view (which is ridiculous in my opinion). You cannot even search the entire document including headers & footers at once through the UI. [Here's a question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/isvvba/thread/b5cc0421-8482-4cee-b70a-b84c4958f9db) at another site that seemed to get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to "force" the Find and Replace dialog to include header and footer text. I recorded a macro while changing header text and got this code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 7/26/2012 by Jimmy Peña
'
  If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
  End If
  If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
  End If
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Selection.TypeText Text:="d"
End Sub
```

I went to View » Header/Footer, deleted a character and typed a new one.

What you probably have to do is Find & replace in VBA:

- Read the contents of the header into a String variable
- Parse the String variable, replacing text if necessary, then
- Write the contents of the String variable back to the header

Repeat for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct code [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) It will do text replacement even in textboxes in footer/header.

```
 Sub FindReplaceAnywhere(ByVal pFindTxt As String, ByVal pReplaceTxt As String)
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  Dim oShp As Shape
TryAgain:
  'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      SearchAndReplaceInStory rngStory, pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
      On Error Resume Next
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
      Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
        If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
          For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
            If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
              SearchAndReplaceInStory oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, _
                  pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Case Else
        'Do Nothing
      End Select
      On Error GoTo 0
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next
End Sub
Sub SearchAndReplaceInStory(ByVal rngStory As Word.Range, _
    ByVal strSearch As String, ByVal strReplace As String)
  With rngStory.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = strSearch
    .Replacement.Text = strReplace
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```